# How to make a DB Connection class to be a Singleton?

Tags: java, singleton

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Class1 class = new Class();
es.execute(class);
```

---

Class1 implements Runnable code to call db connection/class where dbconnection exists.

The problem is, each time Class1 gets called, db connection is created and its overload to system. So, can I instead have just instance of dbconnection class which makes me not create connection each time.

Answer (score 1):

if all the client will have open a static connection and keep it open till application life cycle. In this case, the sql server will be not able to allow creating new connections after a threshold reaches.

So it's advisable to create connection when required and close it when work completes.

You can save the processing and time for creating a connection every time by using connection pooling.

Comment: Connection est.. everytime is a costly process. Instead can i have singleton DB Connector object from which i can access jsut instance

Answer (score 0):

If your app is running on a application server such as Glassfish (and probably Tomcat too) you might want to try the db connection pools - they handle the using and reusing of connections rather well.

That point aside, it's good practice to always close connections after you have finished using them.